# problem about computational complexity

Tags: computational-complexity

Exercise:
Prove that the computational complexity of the binomial coefficient 
\begin{equation*}
\binom{m}{n} 
\end{equation*}
is O($m^{2}$$\log^{2}n$).
using the fact that the computanional complexity of the product of s+1 integers is O($s^{2}\log^{2}M$) where M is the max of them and that T($m!$)=O($m^{2}\log^{2}m$).
I tried with this
\begin{equation*}
\binom{m}{n} = \frac{m!}{n!(m-n)!}=\frac{m(m-1)\dots(m-n+1)}{n!}  
\end{equation*}

So for the numerator we have a computaniol complexity O($(n+2)^{2}\log^{2}m$) because we have n+2 product of integers smaller than m and for the denominator we have a computational complexity O($n^{2}\log^{2}n^{2}$).
Now i know that the coast of the division between two number is T($m=qn+r$)=O($\log q\log n$)=O($\log^{2}n$) since $q<n$. From now on i don't know how to proceed.

Comment: When you get a satisfactory answer for a question of yours, you can accept it. Please, [take a tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how to accept answers and what are the basic functionalities on this site.

Answer (score 1):

On the numerator you multiply $n$ integers, so the complexity is $O((n-1)^2\log^2 m)=O(n^2\log^2m)$.

Also, about the complexity of computing the denominator, you have that
$$O(n^2\log^2n^2)=O(4n^2\log^2n)=O(n^2\log^2n)$$

And for the division, you have $O(\log^2 n!)=O\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\log i\right)^2\right)=O\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\log n\right)^2\right)=\left(\left(n\log n\right)^2\right)=O(n^2\log^2 n)$

The total complexity is the sum of the complexity of computing the numerator, then the denominator and finally do the division. So, you have
\begin{align}
&O((n-1)^2\log^2 m)+O(n^2\log^2n^2)+O(\log^2 n!)\\
=&O(n^2\log^2m)+O(n^2\log^2n)+O(n^2 \log^2 n)\\
=&O(n^2\log^2 m)&\text{ since } n<m
\end{align}